# Herr X war gestern gestorben

Tags: tense, pluperfect

Über den Tod von Helmut Schmidt wird ja auch in den österreichischen Medien ausführlich berichtet. In einer Nachrichtensendung des ORF sagte heute ein Sprecher:

> Der Tod des deutschen Altbundeskanzlers Helmut Schmidt hat große Trauer ausgelöst, der SPD-Politiker **war** gestern im Alter von 96 Jahren gestorben.

Für mich klingt das falsch. Ich meine, das sollte »**ist** gestern ... gestorben« heißen. Mit »war« klingt das irgendwie so, als wäre »gestorben« ein vorübergehender Zustand (so wie »betrunken« oder »in China«), der heute nicht mehr zutrifft.

Allerdings höre ich immer wieder, dass das Wort »war« verwendet wird, wo ich »ist« erwarten würde, besonders häufig zusammen mit dem Wort »gewesen« z.B.:

> Herr Fink schilderte uns den Unfall, er **war** ja selbst in dem Bus gewesen.

Hat der Sprecher hier tatsächlich einen Fehler gemacht, oder trügt mich da mein Sprachgefühl?

Comment: Das sind wir irren Deutschen. Der Engländer würde ja einfach sagen, er "starb", doch wir Deutschen benutzen das Perfekt für Dinge die gestern waren. Und dann fällt einem auf, dass etwas ja irgendwie zeitlich doch in der Vergangenheit liegt und endgültig ist, also braucht man etwas was die Vergangenheit kennzeichnet. Also macht man aus dem "ist" ein "war". Das ist ja eindeutig Vergangenheit. - Aber das ist nur meine Theorie.

Comment: Ja, lustig. Die Zeitform mit dem lateinischen Namen »Perfekt« (*Ida hat gelacht*, *Hans ist gestürzt*) heißt in der Grammatik des österreichischen Deutsch ganz einfach »Vergangenheit«. Im deutschen Deutsch hat das Ding mehrere Namen, einer davon ist »vollendete Gegenwart«. Dieselbe Zeitform gilt also in Deutschland als eine Form der Gegenwart, während sie in Österreich die Standardform für alles ist, was in der Vergangenheit passiert ist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dich trügt dein Sprachgefühl. Das, was du als Zustandspassiv anzusehen scheinst, ist in Wirklichkeit ein Plusquamperfekt, also die Vorvergangenheit.

> Der Tod […] *hat* große Trauer *ausgelöst* (1. Vergangenheitsstufe)
>
> Der SPD-Politiker *war* gestern *gestorben.* (2. Vergangenheitsstufe)

Die 2. Vergangenheitsstufe muss logisch und faktisch *vor* der ersten gewesen sein, denn wenn jemand noch nicht tot ist, kann dessen Tod nicht betrauert werden. Da die 1. Vergangenheitsstufe bereits in der Vergangenheitsform berichtet wird, ist es sprachlich korrekt, für das Vorhergehende die 2. Vergangenheitsstufe zu verwenden.

Ähnlich mit dem Busbeispiel. Er *war* (zu Zeiten des Unfalls) im Bus gewesen, deswegen *hat* er später *schildern können.* Zwei Vergangenheitsstufen.

»Sprachlich korrekt« heißt im Deutschen übrigens nicht »notwendig«. Das Plusquamperfekt kann im Deutschen in fast jedem Fall problemlos durch Perfekt/Präteritum ersetzt werden, im Gegensatz zu anderen Sprachen wie Englisch oder Französisch, wo die Verwendung meistens obligatorisch ist.

Comment: Jaa... Es ist grammatikalisch Plusquamperfekt, aber im HelmutSchmidt-Beispiel sehe ich keine Notwendigkeit. "Der Tod hat Trauer ausgelöst. Er ist im Alter von X Jahren gestorben." Zwei Fakten, keine Verbindung. — Hinzu kommt noch "gestern" plus Plusquamperfekt vertragen sich nicht wirklich gut. Plusquamperfekt verlangt eher Dinge wie "zuvor", "vorher". Ja, "gestern" *kann* trotzdem verwendet werden, es ist aber meist holprig.

Comment: Deine Antwort überzeugt mich als Begründung für das verwendete »war« (daher +1), aber wie Em1 sehe ich hier keine  Notwendigkeit für die Verwendung des Plusquamperfekts, ebensowenig wie im Bus-Beispiel. Das Plusquamperfekt brauche ich Sätzen wie diesem: »Anna war außer Atem, weil sie, bevor sie bei ihrer Tante ankam, so schnell **gelaufen war**.«

Comment: @Em1 Ich würde sogar noch weiter gehen und behaupten, dass es im Deutschen *nie* notwendig ist, deswegen hab ich jetzt noch einen letzten Absatz dazugeschrieben.

Comment: Obiger Kommentar CC @HubertSchölnast

Comment: Kleine Korrektur bzgl. des Englischen. Das Past Perfect *kann* durch Simple Past ersetzt werden, wenn durch Signalwörter erkennbar ist, welche Aktion zuerst stattfand. Siehe http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html: "If the Past Perfect action did occur at a specific time, the Simple Past can be used instead of the Past Perfect when "before" or "after" is used in the sentence. The words "before" and "after" actually tell you what happens first, so the Past Perfect is optional." Davon machen wir im Deutschen viel häufiger Gebrauch als es im Englischen üblich ist.

Comment: Also im Grunde hast du meinen Einwand damit nicht gemildert. Ich bleibe bei dem Standpunkt, dass "war" in dem Satz oben aus grammatischer Sicht falsch ist, weil **keine Vorvergangenheit vorliegt**. Es handelt sich um ein Sache, die zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit passiert. Das benötigt Präteritum in den meisten Sprachen, oder im Deutschen auch Perfekt. Der Teil mit der Trauer ist irrelevant.

Comment: Man kann es auch nochmal anders betrachten. Der Tod ist der Auslöser der Trauer. Genau das steht im ersten Teil. Die Trauer wurde aber quasi 'im selben Moment' ausgelöst. Ja, die Menschen erfahren es erst im Laufe des Tages oder am nächsten. Aber es sind nicht zwei Aktionen die klar hintereinander ausgeführt wurde, wie in bspw. "Er ging nach Hause, nachdem er seine Arbeit beendet hatte." Hier ist übrigens das Perfekt bzw. Präteritum falsch, sowohl im Deutschen als auch im Englischen btw. "...nachdem er seine Arbeit beendet hat." ist falsch.

Comment: Und noch ein Aspekt: Als Nachricht ist der Tod einer Person am Folgetag ein bereits in der Vergangenheit abgeschlossenes Ereignis, das zeitlich vor aktuellen Nachrichten zu der betreffenden Person (ausführliche Nachrufe, Reaktionen, Perspektiven) liegt. Die Formulierung im Plusquamperfekt ist zumindest im öffentlich rechtlichen deutschen Rundfunk und Fernsehen üblich.

Answer (score 5):

Der Sprecher hat hier einen Fehler gemacht, der jedoch recht üblich ist. Sehr typisch ist es in Verbindung mit *sein*, wie du selbst erwähnst.

> Wo warst du gestern gewesen?

Der Satz *kann* richtig sein, wenn eine Referenz zu einem Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit vorliegt. Der Zeitpunkt (also "gestern") gehört übrigens strikt genommen in den Teil des Satzes, der den Referenzzeitpunkt bestimmt.

> Wo warst du gewesen, bevor du gestern nach Hause gefahren bist.
>   Wo bist du gewesen, nachdem du gestern nach Hause gefahren warst.

Nicht selten wird aber in beiden Teilsätzen die gleiche Zeitform gewählt. Das ist akzeptabel, weil immer noch verständlich ist, welche Aktion zuerst stattfand. Hier der erste Satz nochmals als Beispiel in inkorrekter Form:

> Wo warst du gewesen, bevor du gestern nach Hause gefahren warst.
>   Wo bist du gewesen, bevor du gestern nach Hause gefahren bist.

Häufig wird aber auch die grammatische Form der Vorvergangenheit in Verbindung zur Gegenwart verwendet. Ich kann nicht begründen warum, eine schwache Vermutung habe ich oben im Kommentar erwähnt, bin aber selbst nicht sehr davon überzeugt.

Begründen könnte man aber, warum der Sprecher in diesem konkreten Beispiel zur Vorvergangenheit gegriffen hat. Der Satz kann so wie er dort steht durchaus aus das Gefühl vermitteln, dass es sich um zwei Aktionen handelt, die in der Vergangenheit nacheinander stattfanden.

> 1. Helmut Schmidt starb.
> 2. Alle Menschen trauern seitdem.

Das ist aber im Beispiel nicht ganz richtig. Die beiden Fakten (Tod + Trauer) liegen im ersten Teil des Satzes bereits vor.

> Der Tod hat Trauer ausgelöst.

Genau das beschreibt jetzt unseren Referenzzeitpunkt, und dieser entspricht dem Zeitpunkt des Todes. Die Tatsache, dass "der Politiker gestern im Alter von 96 Jahren starb", **liegt nicht vor dem Todeszeitpunkt**, sondern beschreibt den selben Zeitpunkt. Es handelt sich hier nur um einen weiteren Fakt, der vollkommen unabhängig zur ausgelösten Trauer ist. Korrekt ist also:

> Der Tod hat Trauer ausgelöst. Er **ist** gestern im Alter von 96 Jahren gestorben.

Damit Plusquamperfekt berechtigt wäre, müsste der Satz etwa wiefolgt lauten:

> Nachdem gestern im Alter von 96 Jahren Helmut Schmidt gestorben war, wurde Trauer über seinen Tod ausgelöst.

Ich hinterfrage an der Stelle jetzt nicht, ob das sogar grammatisch richtig wäre, aber der Satz käme so wohl keinem Muttersprachler über die Lippen.

Fazit:
Der Satz ist grammatikalisch falsch, weil keine Vorvergangenheit vorliegt.

Comment: An sich muss man schon sterben, *bevor* der Tod Trauer auslöst. Von einer Gleichzeitigkeit kann grade hier eigentlich keine Rede sein.

Comment: @tofro Und? Habe ich irgendwo etwas anderes behauptet?