# What is the origin of the two past tenses in German?

Tags: history, tense, past

In my German class, we learned that there are two past tenses, which we referred to as the "narrative" and "conversational," the former only being used for writing, and the other used exclusively for verbal communication. I'm sure it's much more nuanced than this, as it was only a 100-level course.

This is such an alien concept to me as an English speaker, I wonder how it came about.

Comment: What's a 100-level course? Sounds long:)

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1180/30056 And here is e.g. a website that expands on further details (albeit in german): https://deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/der-gebrauch-der-tempora-zeiten/gebrauch-praeteritum-perfekt/

Comment: A 100 level course code indicates that you will be engaging with discipline knowledge and skills at a foundation level. These courses are normally studied in your first year of full-time study.

Comment: The “narrative” past isn't about the past. In English neither. You don't write “Scotty will beam up Kirk.” or “Scotty beams up Kirk.” but “Scotty beamed up Kirk.” The narrative puts you in a far more away future in which the events of the narrative were past. It's the same in German. — What's different in German is this narrative tense isn't used for past events of reality.

Comment: How is it an alien concept?  It's just like in English, you can say "I ate" or "I have eaten"

Comment: It is an alien concept, because I was told that it is conventional to use one for written language and one for spoken language. I know that English has multiple past tenses, but we don't have a clear distinction as to their function like that.

Comment: You think you don't have a clear distinction to their function like that. That's because you're a native speaker. If you took English lessons (as in, "foreigners learn English"), you would be swamped with rules on all the clear distinctions on how to use the two past tenses "properly". In my experience, few of those rules are followed by the majority of native speakers, and even when they are used, the native speakers usually don't know the rules. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Luaan (which is another way of saying the rules are wrong but still better than having no rules at all)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I interpret the question as: How did the functional difference between a "narrative" and a "conversational" past come about? I assume the development of the forms is not relevant (i.e. the fact that German, like English, combined an auxiliary with a past participle to form a new tense).

I'll try to answer with a few (hopefully uncontroversial) remarks. Anything more detailed and the answer would have to turn into a book (or dissertation).

In [Upper German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_German) dialects, the preterite had been lost by the end of the Early New High German period, around 1650 ([Oberdeutscher Präteritumschwund](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutscher_Pr%C3%A4teritumschwund), which I have seen translated as *preterite decay*). A potential reason for this loss that is commonly mentioned is a phonological phenomenon called [apocope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope), whereby the final *-e* in preterite forms such as *lebte* was dropped, rendering them homophonous to the present *lebt*.

In those dialects where the preterite had been lost, the perfect took over all functions of the preterite and any difference in use between preterite and perfect was lost. However, since the *Präteritumschwund* only affected Upper German dialects and the preterite was preserved in Central and Low German dialects, as well as the developing standard language, dialect speakers from the South still encountered the preterite, specifically when dealing with the standard language as it was taught in schools and used in print. This, to me, can easily explain the connection between the preterite and written language (as well as a more formal register) and the common teaching aid of characterising the preterite as narrative past.

However, another factor is involved. To this day, functional differences between the two pasts have survived, which is not surprising given the fact that the preterite was preserved in many dialects, as well as the standard language. For instance, when greeting someone you have not seen for a long time, you might say:

> Hallo! Wir haben uns aber lange nicht gesehen. Ich habe dich vermißt.

Using the preterite in this situation is out of the question. The specific meaning of the perfect is characterised in various ways by different people; however, the phrase *relevant for the present* is often used, i.e., in the given example, not having seen you and having missed you is affecting my current state, explaining my emotional reaction and so on. The fact that the preterite is missing the meaning component of being relevant for the present makes it ideally suited for narrative texts.

In short: Loss of the preterite in certain dialects, while being preserved in others as well as the developing standard, in interplay with a functional difference between preterite and perfect that makes the former more suited to narration.

Finally, note that the fact that the preterite is used for narration does not mean it is not used in spoken language. As is to be expected, speakers from the North use it more frequently than those from the South. Also, the fact that there can be meaning differences between the preterite and the perfect does not mean that there are no contexts where they can be used interchangeably – in many contexts, they are used interchangeably.

Comment: @CarstenS I assume that OP is not surprised by the fact that there is a perfect, since their native tongue has one as well, but by the fact that the difference between preterite and perfect has been characterised to them as one between narration and conversation.

Comment: @infinitezero The idea is that if there are two pasts, one being used for X and the other for Y, what happens if one past is lost? Most likely, the other past will be used for X as well as Y. (Of course, theoretically, another tense such as the present could be used for Y, but I don't think the present took over the function of the preterite.)

Comment: @infinitezero We seem to be talking about different stages of the process. You're at the point where *er lebt'* is being given up as confusing. Note that the functional difference between present and past is completely intact, as it is for nowadays for *lebte* in *wenn/als ich dort lebte*. I'm at the point where *er lebt(e)* is gone and speakers have to use *er hat gelebt* in all contexts where they previously used *lebt(e)*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot follow your line of argumentation at all. Remarking that the suffix of the preterite was dropped thus prompting a potential reanalysis of the preterite as present leaves out the use of the perfect at the stage that you posit. More importantly, the fact that the preterite has been increasingly replaced by the perfective in Romance (French, Italian) calls for a cross-linguistic explanation (for which I have some hypotheses to be illustrated in case of interest).

Comment: @Nico The fact is the preterite was lost. Homophony between present and preterite is just one hypothesis as to why that may have been the case; there are others. I'm interested in what happens later, i.e. when the preterite is reintroduced to certain dialect speakers via schools and literature. I agree that I left out a lot, but the answer is long enough as it is. Feel free to add your own!

Comment: @DavidVogt I think we are dealing with a phenomenon of frequency of usage and normativity vs one of grammatically encoded ASPECT, as it holds for English. In German, we would most likely say "Letzte Woche bin ins Kino gegangen" and write in an official context "Letzte Woche ging ins Kino".  This is a matter of register. Such option is not yielded in English, where the difference "accomplished" vs "accomplished and still relevant for the present" is the main criterion.

Comment: @Nico: belleslettres.eu sees a decided parallel in southern but not northern German switching from preterite to perfect for the past like Italian or French. The correlate this with catholic vs. protestant (via latin). This is in the long post linked in my answer. And the video has a long explanation of how the perfect evolved.

Comment: Where is the link? Could you please post it again? I doubt that religion can mould grammar, but one never knows...

Comment: @Nico: https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/verb/tempus-aspekt-prateritum-perfekt.php. They don't *claim* religion molds grammar. They observe that a similar "advance" of perfect has taken place in French and Italian. And they also say that the perfect is a very normal way of expressing the past in latin (depending on the verb). [I have no idea how French passé composé and Italian passato prossimo evolved and I don't know latin but I read they didn't use auxiliary have]. They say nowadays catholic southern Europe uses perfect and protestant northern Europe kept the Germanic preterite and argue

Comment: ... that even the Irish system of tenses is closer to the Latin than to the English system of tenses. [I read in wikipedia that within Italian, the predominat perfect use is in the north but not in the south - so one may as well check the alternative hypothesis that this is a regional phenomenon surrounding the Alps - AFAIK catholic Poland uses preterite at least that's what I as an interested linguistic lay person gather from the tiny bits and pieces of French, Italian and Polish I speak]. Also the time line would need to be considered. After all, the German & European north also used to be

Comment: ... catholic before reformation. So any influence via [religion-related] exposure to Latin was there as well.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica I can confirm that central and southern Italy have retained the *passato remoto* (the Italian equivalent to the praeteritum) while the arguably less catholic northern Italy has lost it. I suspect religion is a red herring here: in Italy at least the demarcation line is evidently the Appenines (the so-called "La Spezia-Rimini line", which is a fairly sharp linguistic boundary for numerous features).

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica The article is interesting, but its tenets are not plausible from a linguistic point of view. 1) There is no explanation as for why the influence of Latin might have triggered this divide. One could argue that masses held in Latin are the trigger, but then again: how often do they take place and how many people attend them? 2) The divide between Northern and Southern Europe is not as clear-cut as posited (see more below in another comment of mine).

Comment: @DenisNardin Linguistically, religion cannot bring about language change or control language preservation. What you write about Italian is basically correct, but not applicable altogether. The northern region Veneto, for example is quite religious, but does not use "passato remoto" in spoken language. The same holds for the region Piedmont.

Comment: @Nico There was literally a clear-cut line, the limes, dividing Germanic tribes from Raetia and other provinces, (simply speaking, the Franks?). The correlation to confession might be real, but not causation, rather due to real cultural boundaries. The Franks vs Swabian dispute is infamous, so surmizing Oberdeutsch, as David has cited, is, I guess, not quite correct either. Strong verbs could not loose preterite through ellision.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there is the same distinction as in English. The preterite, in theory, puts you somewhat closer together with the events, thus the alternative name "Mitvergangenheit". You are with the past, so to say. Whereas the perfect is, well... *perfect* (i.e. closed, over, done, no longer actual), it's definitively no longer happening, nor are its effects.

Except, well, *nobody* uses it that way. Nobody! Alright, your teacher in elementary school might, if she is from the north...

German is **much** more relaxed when it comes to time, especially in speech (and even more in colloquial speech). For example, it can be perfectly correct to use present tense for past events:

> Wir waren gestern im Kino, und wie wir gerade rauskommen ist da doch dieser Typ, der hat mich total blöd angemacht.

<sub>(Note: It really *should* be "als" in the above sentence, not "wie", but you know... unless you are in elementary school, it's just perfectly fine. Native speakers, except for the most obnoxious pedants, won't object or raise an eyebrow.)</sub>

There you go, you have one event within a single sentence which is in the past (and very demonstrably so, it was the day before) but you have **three** tenses (including present time!) in it. And believe me, it will not strike anyone as weird, or clumsy, or even wrong.

Generally, you are good to go (99%) by simply using the perfect. Using the preterite *in speech* will in most (though not all) situations make you sound either a bit snobby, queer, or antiquated.

Similarly, you can use present time for the future just fine in most situations:

> Wenn ich mit dem Studium fertig bin, gehe ich nach Indien.

Very obviously, according to the sentence, you *are not yet* done, but that doesn't matter in any way (nor does it matter that you do not actually intend to *walk* to India, and how could one possibly guess that *go* or *walk* actually means *relocate* in this context!). However, nobody who is at his senses will say something like:

> Wenn ich mit dem Studium fertig sein werde, werde ich nach Indien umziehen.

or even (to point out the correct sequence of events):

> Nachdem ich mit dem Studium fertig geworden sein werde, werde ich ...

While it's arguably *possible* to say that, you will with absolute certitude attract puzzled looks from everybody around you.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the interplay between the tenses, but my question is really about why the function of these tenses diverged. In English, I can say or write "I ate," and "I have eaten," and it doesn't attract any comment. Just like you said, using the preterite in conversation will look strange, I was told using the perfect in writing also looks strange.

Comment: No, in English (UK at least), you can't say "Last week I have eaten a delicious pizza". No way, sorry!

Comment: @Nico Correct, but you can't write it that way either. It looks just as strange to me written as it sounds when it's spoken. This isn't the case for German, right? If I say "Ich ass die Pizza" aloud, it draws attention in a way that "Ich habe die Pizza gegessen" doesn't. But not if I write it down. That is my understanding, anyway.

Comment: Please rephrase. Your English is not understandable.

Comment: @Nico In English, the construct "I have eaten some pizza last week" sounds wrong inherently, whether spoken written or sent with smoke signals.

In German, there are two constructs for the same idea that are used in different mediums, and crossing the two sounds strange to a native German speaker.

This is my understanding of the situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in all my comments above.

Answer (score 2):

The [belleslettres](https://www.belleslettres.eu) (BL) have a [long post and video  about "Präteritum oder Perfekt"](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/verb/tempus-aspekt-prateritum-perfekt.php) and an additional [short video on tenses in non-fictional texts](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/verb/perfekt-prateritum-alltagstext.php) which you may want to have a look at.

- They start by stating that Germanic languages used to have 2 tenses: past and not past.  Not past covers everything from present over factual, always-true (gnomic), time-independent to future. And this is still the case in German, just that in Southern (High) German, the perfect has taken over the function of the preterite, while the North kept the preterite.
- But in contrast to other Germanic languages, German has 3 systems of tenses for different types of text: spoken vs. narrative (fiction) vs. factual written.

---

1. In everyday spoken German BL say that 50 years ago there was still quite a distinction between Southern (incl. Austria and German Switzerland) and Northern German: the Northerners used the same construction like all other Germanic languages to express past things: the preterite.  The south used perfect instead, and this is *mostly* the standard way in spoken German now - BL decidedly link that to mass communication. (There are other north vs. south language differences, where the northern version has become standard, e.g. *wegen* + genitive)

   - BL also points out that the use of perfect to express the past in spoken language is also common in romance languages like Italian and French (coming from Latin perfect [+ imperfect]). They see a correlation in Catholic Europe using perfect, and Protestant Europe using preterite.
2. Literary German (narrative) uses preteritum. They call this not a tempus for the past, but say it has the same use as the present in spoken language.
   (I may add that that in a quick thought experiment of telling a tale, e.g. for a child, the past comes naturally to me and not only for fairy tales starting with "Once upon a time..."/"Es war einmal...").
   They argue that this is not a temporal past since narratives taking place in the future are still told in preteritum, and it is also used for things that are independent of time.

   - Nowadays, narrative German uses plusquamperfect analogously to perfect in spoken language. BL cites Schiller using past for that as well.
   - Present/perfect appear in narrative in dialogues.
   - There are some narratives (novels) written in present/perfect instead of past/plusquamperfect. This may happen for artistic reasons. Or for juvenile literature (? Jugendroman) BL claims they have a connotation of the reader not being able to deal with past/plusquamperfect and that they sell badly in general.
3. Non-literary (non fictional, non narrative?) texts form a third category: technical, scientific, journalistic, ... texts.

   - Present [not-past], perfect and preterite are used.
   - Present is the standard tense (in particular for everything that is factual in a time independent manner: pi equals 3. ).
   - preterite is the past for imperfective verbs ("befragte den Zeugen"/asked the witness)
   - perfect produces an imperfective form of a perfective verb (as a counterpart to e.g. *ge-* historically making an imperfective verb perfective). Example *entscheiden* (to decide):

     ```
                 action finishes                
     Ich entscheide        | ich habe entschieden
     ----------------------+------------------------------------------> time
     action changing state | (ongoing) state (after finished action)      
     perfective            | imperfective
     ```
   - Using the preterite of a perfective Verb marks that part as "narration", so both "Das Amtsgericht hat 1910 entschieden ..." and "Das Gericht entschied 1910 ..." are possible, but carry slightly different meaning.

Comment: Somehow, you lost me in the very last two items. In particular, as a native German speaker (from Southern Germany, which may be relevant), I do not perceive any difference in meaning between "Das Amtsgericht hat 1910 entschieden" and "Das Amtsgericht entschied 1910".

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I would like to add a few things simply from my personal observation.

1.) As stated before, all past tenses have their specific function, so you will actually find **all** of them in written texts.

Examples:

> Da sah Jenny, die so etwas noch nie erlebt hatte, dass ihr Fahrrad gestohlen worden war.
>
> Die Unwetter haben inzwischen die Hauptstadt erreicht. "Wir sind vorbereitet" sagte ein Pressesprecher.

And of course, there are some cases where the past tense is commonly used in spoken language too, e.g.:

> An dem Tag war ich krank.
>
> Das lief jetzt nicht nach Plan.

So, it's hard to make a clear distinction between "narrative" and "conversational".

2.) I suppose, in many cases, the popularity of the perfect tense is simply because it is much easier to build (usually just add "ge-") and hence more convenient to use:

> fahren / gefahren -vs- fuhr
>
> lesen / gelesen -vs- las

3.) In slang or sometimes as a personal quirk, some people even use the past perfect commonly, kind of "doubling" the past tense for emphasis:

> Warst du da schon gewesen?
>
> Ich hatte dazu einfach keine Lust gehabt.

I think this is similar to a double-negative in English.

Comment: I claim that in your second example, past perfect would be correct... "Die Unwetter hatten inzwischen die Hauptstadt erreicht"

Comment: With respect to your third point, I'd like to refer to a question from a few years ago: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26543/1224

Comment: @Em1 I was kinda thinking of a headline / newspaper in that case.

Comment: "Das lief jetzt nicht nach Plan." - that doesn't sound like natural, spoken language to me. "Das ist jetzt nicht nach Plan gelaufen." would be the vastly preferred form, at least here in South-Western Germany. For the first sentence, it's indeed more ambiguous - both "An dem Tag war ich krank." and "An dem Tag bin ich krank gewesen." sound equally idiomatic to me.

Answer (score -1):

comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question is trying to accomplish, because it seems to assume that the distinctive use in written or oral speech were strictly proscribed and followed--which is not the case. Then it asked more broadly for the origin of the pasts, while only concerned about the false dichotomy, but going further, potentially expecting a clue from this for that.

---

Today, It is true that preterite is rarely used colloquially. This can have several underlying reasons. A reason not mentioned yet in other answers is that strong verbs inflect irregularly. This is difficult. The relation between *ich mag* and *möchte* is not even recognized (took me only twenty years) and they are thus treated as separate verbs. For the most part we just immitate what we hear, so we follow the past. Reasons that facilitate the prevalence of distinctive preferences also counted in the past.

In the past, as @DavidVogt points out, several developments happened, which were perhaps not semantic, but phonetically motivated. I criticized that very good answer for it did not touch upon strong verbs (admittedly, *I read not the article that it has linked*), so consider this: They suffered from sound change much worse than simple regular preterite forms. It's so bad, that [Grundfragen der Umlautphonemisierung] are not fully understood yet, for example. Forms like *?ich dächte, ?bräuchte* (cp En *?thunk*, *?brung*), seem substandard. I'd say that after vowel shift, the strong verbs were perhaps not euphonic anymore. English even completely lost subjunctive inflections except in a closed class of verbs. It's hard to say which loss dragged the other ones down with them.<sup>[1]</sup> There really is no answer I am aware of, I'm affraid. Obviously we can hardly tell what was spoken, only what was written! As paper, ink and time is costly, scribes went to extreme ends to make the best use of it. Incidently, they would also be predestined to be taught in the proper forms of the grammar, and phonetics would hardly even play a role, except for speech transcripts. Obviously, the shorter preterite saves costs.

In much earlier past had be come these tenses to form. Indo-Germanic --the hypothetical last common ancestor of German and Indic, so to speak, today widely called Proto-Indo-European-- supposedly had a more powerful inflection system, as Sanskrit, Greek, etc attest to. This is mostly out of scope, so suffice to say that the origin of the participle prefix *ge-* in German is apparently not well understood, and might be a multifacetted problem, including tangents to *geh-* (*gehen*, confer *gana in Guus Kroonen's dictionary). The weak inflections supposedly developed later than strong inflections --which stem from Grammatischer Wechsel, Ablaut patterns in Proto-Indo-European-- perhaps in response to these loosing their charm not only on phonetic grounds, but also driven by semantic shift.

---

**Afterthought:** The Konjunktiv moods present a similar situation. This stuation is still more difficult to describe, so suffice to say that many forms are either obsolete (*ich würf*) or indistinct (*ich schalte*) and thus often replaced by an auxilary construction, i.e. in reported speech (*Er sagt ich würde werfen, ich würde schalten*) or irrealis (*er sagt ich hätte geworfen*--that en.wiktionary names plusquam perfect subjunctive II), which can get kind of cumbersome (*ich hätte Geld gehabt*, *ich würde geworfen haben*) and error prone (substandard *hab ich dich getroffen* [?gehabt]*?*). So it's become common concensus to simplify (*ich würde Geld haben*) when a report is neither decidedly potential nor irrealias and the tempus inappropriate.

---

[Grundfragen der Umlautphonemisierung]: Eine strukturelle Analyse des nordgermanischen i/j-Umlauts unter Berücksichtigung der älteren Runeninschriften. (Michael Schulte)--Review by Anatoly Liberman in Alvismal is free to read online

[1]: A similar topic might be strong inflection with *Schwebelaut i/e* as in *ich werfe, du wirfst, wir werfen*, from Middle High German, but Upper German *i/e* in singular/plural respectively, from uncertain origin (see Watts, West, Solms 2013, Zur Verbmorphologie germanischer Sprachen, pp. 40-45).

Comment: To address your comment, as I said in the OP, I'm sure it's much more complicated than I put it. But it was presented to me in the class that, broadly speaking, the preterite is not used in conversation, and the perfect is not used in writing. Is this not a fair characterization?

Comment: Trivially speaking, the preterite is used to inflect the auxiliary verb in plusquam perfect tense, at least. I'm aware that's not what you mean, and *ich war einkaufen* for example is something else, more frequent than either *habe eingekauft* or *kaufte ein* (subject to regional variation anyhow). As everybody else said, the preterite is not completely foreign to oral speach and conversational tone. It's just that "*Ich habe eine Fahrkarte gekauft*" is a very obvious extension to "*Ich habe eine Fahrkarte*". Whereas *ich kaufte* is, rarely spoken indeed.

Answer (score -3):

I have never heard the expressions "narrative" and "conversational" past tense, but I am fairly sure I know what is meant.

Concerning grammar: Similarly as English, German has three past tenses: Past Simple, Present Perfect Simple and Past Perfect Simple (though English has more, e.g. Past Progressive), and there are clear rules how to use them.

When writing about the past you should grammatically correctly use *Past Simple* ("Ich las das Buch"). This is *narrative past*. However, when speaking to other other people it is common to use Present Perfect ("Ich habe das Buch gelesen"). This is *conversational past* which is  grammatically not correct. In my opinion it is an unfortunate habit, but if you *speak* grammatically correct, it would probably be perceived as somewhat pretentious. Weird, isn't it?

There are exceptions. In conversation auxiliary verbs are usually correctly used in their Past Simple form. For example, you would always say "Ich hatte Angst" or "Ich war krank" and not "Ich habe Angst gehabt" or "Ich bin krank gewesen".

Comment: This does not try to answer the question.

Comment: I disagree with your last paragraph -- all these forms are in use in conversation.

Comment: This is not about "correct" or "incorrect", it's just the established usage. And it's more complicated than that, see e.g. https://deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/der-gebrauch-der-tempora-zeiten/gebrauch-praeteritum-perfekt/

Comment: @OliverMason I do agree with the last paragraph! Of course, you can use both forms, but using *Präteritum* for auxiliary verbs is way more common than *Perfekt*, at least all people I know commonly do this, including myself. This becomes apparent when you combine auxiliary and non-auxiliary verbs: "Ich *war* krank und *habe* ein Buch *gelesen*." is what I would choose to say over the other possible combinations "Ich bin krank gewesen und habe ein Buch gelesen.", "Ich war krank und las ein Buch.", and (most awkwardly sounding imo) "Ich bin krank gewesen und las ein Buch.".

Comment: @sebrockm Yes, in such combinations I'd agree. But I'd say _Ich bin gestern ins Kino gegangen_ as opposed to _Gestern ging ich ins Kino_ (Or actually better _Gestern war ich im Kino_).

Comment: @OliverMason But *gehen* is no auxiliary verb :) So you choosing *bin gegangen* over *ging* further proves the point. And choosing *ich war im Kino* over *ich bin im Kino gewesen* proves it even more.

Comment: @OliverMason: belleslettres argues that 50 years ago, there was still a distinction between the north and south of Germany in that in spoken language in the north past was indicated with simple past in spoken language while in the south perfect was used and that the standardization (due to TV [+ radio + ...]) is not yet quite finished. I can only say that I live quite in the middle, and both *Ich war im Kino.* and *Ich bin ins Kino gegangen.* sound correct to me.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica I grew up in both the South and then the North in the 70s, so that fits :)

Comment: (-1) This is horribly prescriptive and useless as a description of the actual state of the German language. The only thing that sounds weird in all this are constructions like “grammatically correctly use” and “speak grammatically correct”.

Comment: This does not address the question, which is not about the actual state of the language, but about how that state came about.

Comment: @FredFrey Thank you for giving feedback and not only downvoting anonymously. Unfortunately this only happens very rarely although it matters to understand the reasons,

Comment: I'm not going to vote in any direction. I do support your general statement, but I just think the way you address it is "very thin ice". Most notably, I think it's wrong to say that the conversational past is grammatically incorrect. It's true that in German we use the perfect tense in a rather awkward way and clearly distinct to other languages (e.g. English, Spanish), but that's just how it's developed. And hence it's correct.